# How to update multiple databases in parallel

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, parallelism

As part of performance regression testing of a backup product, one stage of the workflow requires updating a single table that exists in multiple databases on a single SQL Server instance and then taking incremental/differential backups of all the databases.

Currently I'm running the update query serially on each database via `sp_ineachdb` from the [SQL Server First Responder Kit](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/dev/sp_ineachdb.sql). `sp_ineachdb` executes the given query in the context of each database (in this case only user DBs).

I'm looking for advice on how to parallelize this update process as I have a highly performant SQL Server environment and it would be nice to be able to cut the completion time by a factor of 2 or more.

The query looks like this:

```
declare @cmd varchar(max)
declare @SqlError int

set @cmd = '

UPDATE [dbo].[Updates]
SET UN_ID = LTRIM(STR(FLOOR(RAND()*(10000000000-100000000+1))+100000000)),
    WHO_ID = LTRIM(STR(FLOOR(RAND()*(10000000000-100000000+1))+100000000)),
    CDC_ID = LTRIM(STR(FLOOR(RAND()*(10000000000-100000000+1))+100000000)),
    PracticeName = NEWID(),
    Incidents_2013 = RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 1000000,
    Incidents_2014 = RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 1000000,
    Incidents_2015 = RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 1000000,
    Incidents_2016 = RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 1000000,
    Incidents_2017 = RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 1000000,
    Incidents_2018 = RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 1000000
'

exec @sqlError = sp_ineachdb @command = @cmd, @user_only = 1;
```

I am running these updates from an automation framework. I could theoretically execute a separate C# program, but I'd prefer a T-SQL or Powershell solution.

IO blocking should not be an issue as primary storage is over 40 Gibps iSCSI vVols.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the Powershell script in [Backup SQL Server Databases in Parallel with PowerShell](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4974/backup-sql-server-databases-in-parallel-with-powershell/) by Pablo Echeverria on MSSQLTips.com to suit my purposes. I have so far seen update speed increases between 1.2x and 1.6x.